# Parsing javascript date string to timestamp. the tz info is in the date!

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, timestamp

I have to parse a javascript date string to a timestamp. If the date string has the TZ info, why do I have to supply a TZ object in the DateTime constructor and again with setTimezone()? Is there an easier way to do this that is aware of the TZ info in the date?

```
$s = 'Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)';
$dt_obj = new DateTime($s, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); /* why? the TZ info is in the date string */

// again
$dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo 'timestamp  ' , $dt_obj->getTimestamp(), '<br>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you really have to put it there ?

Can you just not use this :

```
$s = 'Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)';
$dt_obj = new DateTime($s);
```

Note : the second parameter to [`DateTime::__construct`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) is optionnal : its default value is `null`

And, later, you can do :

```
var_dump($dt_obj->getTimestamp());
var_dump($dt_obj->getTimezone()->getName());
```

And you'll get :

```
int 1268330400
string '-05:00' (length=6)
```

If EST is [Eastern Time Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone), I suppose it's OK, as it's `UTC-5` ?

*As a sidenote : I'm in France, which is at `UTC+1` ; so it doesn't seem that my local timezone has any influence*

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier & just use strtotime():

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)');
```

Comment: I don't believe this will maintain the timezone information, which may or may not be what the OP needs (depending on what he wants to do with the DateTime object afterward).

Comment: strtotime not TZ aware:

    $timestamp = strtotime('Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)');
    echo '<pre>$timestamp: '; echo $timestamp; echo '</pre>';

    $timestamp = strtotime('Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (PST)');
    echo '<pre>$timestamp: '; echo $timestamp; echo '</pre>';

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the deal. It is aware of TZ in the date string. Just set the default timezone to anything using date_default_timezone_set (). Doesn't matter what -- it just has to be set.

```
//date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$s = 'Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)';
$dt_obj = new DateTime($s);
echo 'timestamp  ' , $dt_obj->getTimestamp(), '<br>';
/* 1268330400 */

$s = 'Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)';
$dt_obj = new DateTime($s);
echo 'timestamp  ' , $dt_obj->getTimestamp(), '<br>';   
/* 1268341200 <- different, good */
```

A lot easier than:

```
$s = 'Thu Mar 11 2010 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)';
$dt_obj = new DateTime($s, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
$dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo 'timestamp  ' , $dt_obj->getTimestamp();
/* 1268330400 */
```

Comment: And the date_default_timezone_set should always be set anyway in config/init or php.ini,  so you wouldn't normally need date_default_timezone_set right there in the code

Comment: I'm on php 5.3 which throws exception on new DateTime($s) (no second arg) if date_default_timezone_set not set